# What exactly is running when I run ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -ext_output test.mp4?

Tags: python, command-line, google-colaboratory, yolo, darknet

I am very new to coding in general, and even newer to darknet and yolo. What is exactly is happening when I run ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -ext_output test.mp4? I understand that it takes the names, cfg, and weights, but what exactly is happening? Does ./darknet detector demo call some file, and where is that file located. Also, is there a place I can find all of the flags like -ext_output?

Edit: I've read through the majority of files on AlexeyAB darknet GitHub but I still haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: What code do you execute? Did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: It is from the AlexeyAB Darknet GitHub

Answer (score 1):

```
./darknet detector demo
```

It's calling the compiled C code where **detector** is in src/detector.c and **demo** is in src/demo.c. **demo** is also a method and you can find it here
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/demo.c#L133

You can find most of the commands explained here:
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/#how-to-use-on-the-command-line